# Find the shaded area of ​the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Find the shaded area of ​​the figure below
[image]

My progress
$ELH: =(6+r)^2
=(12-r)^2 +(6-r)^2 \implies \boxed{r = 12(2-\sqrt3})\\
S = 144\pi(7-4\sqrt3)$

Would this resolution be correct?

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: This is absolutely accurate